# The letter grade doesn't return the value based on criteria

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32, irvine32

In this code, I am trying to generates up to 25 random integers between 50 and 100 inclusive, depending on user input, calculates the letter grade and prints the integer and the letter grade

The problem that I have is that the letter grade doesn't return the letter grade based on the scale (ex: 0-59= F, 90-100= A). It keeps on printing F

This is my code that returns the letter grade

```
AlphaGrade PROC USES EAX            ;letter grade

cmp EAX, 90

jae gradeA                          ;jump if grade>= 90

cmp EAX, 80

jae gradeB                          ;jump if grade >= 80

cmp EAX, 70                     

jae gradeC                          ;jump if grade >= 70

cmp EAX, 60

jae gradeD                          ;jump if grade >= 60

cmp EAX, 0

jae gradeF                          ;jump if grade < 60

gradeA:

mov al, 'A'                         ;mov grade A to al

call WriteChar                      ;display the letter

jmp okay                            ;jump to okay


gradeB:

mov al, 'B'                         ;mov grade B to al

call WriteChar                      ;display the letter

jmp okay                            ;jump to okay

gradeC:

mov al, 'C'                         ;mov grade C to al

call WriteChar                      ;display the letter

jmp okay                            ;jump to okay

gradeD:

mov al, 'D'                         ;mov grade D to al

call WriteChar                      ;display the letter

jmp okay                            ;jump to okay

gradeF:

mov al, 'F'                         ;mov grade F to al

call WriteChar                      ;display the letter

jmp okay                            ;jump to okay


okay:

ret

AlphaGrade ENDP
```

Comment: Is this homework? Did you run this in a debugger?

Comment: yes I did try to run in a debugger. It only keeps on printing F for every random generated number.

Comment: Look at the value of EAX when you call AlphaGrade. In your top portion of code you are writing out with WriteChar which may be smashing EAX before you can pass it to AlphaGrade. In fact, you smash EAX when you write out the space character. Preserve EAX (push eax) before calling WriteDec and then retrieve it (pop eax) right before calling AlphaGrade.

Comment: Oh yes I didnt realize that! thanks! I have another question. So instead of writing space character, my teacher wants me to use gotoxy instead. 'mov DH, 5' 'mov DL, 1' 'call gotoxy'. I was assuming it will be something like this, but I'm not sure of where I should call this.